# How do you get bundle config to use multiple build options?

Tags: config, bundle, bundler

I'm attempting to use bundler to install some packages, the command I want to use is:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

However, since [libxml2 is being a jerk](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk), I need to setup the config before hand with a command like so:

```
bundle config --local build.nokogiri --with-xml2-include=dir1 --with-xml2-lib=dir2 --with-xslt-include=dir3 --with-xslt-lib=dir4
```

But when I look at the `.bundle/config` file, I see:

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__NOKOGIRI: --with-xml2-include=dir1
  --with-xml2-lib=dir2 --with-xslt-include=dir3 --with-xslt-lib=dir4
```

You'll notice the `dir2`, `dir3`, and `dir4` appear on the next line, not on the same line as the `dir1`.  This is a problem because when I type `bundle config` to display the current config, I see that it isn't recognizing second line of configs:

```
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
build.nokogiri
Set for your local app (/path/app/.bundle/config): "--with-xml2-include=dir1"
```

How do I get `bundle config` to retain multiple build options?  FYI, I already tried putting quotes around them, and removing the `--local` -- they yielded the same result.

I'm using bundler version 1.3.5

Answer (score 0):

In my case (`bundler-1.17.2`, `bundler-2.0.2`) it was passing all the arguments as one:

```
$ bundle config --local build.openssl \
--with-openssl-lib=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0 \
--with-openssl-include=/usr/include/openssl-1.0
$ bundle install
```

`$BUNDLE_PATH/ruby/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/openssl-2.0.0/gem_make.out`:

```
/home/yuri/.rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby \
-I /home/yuri/.rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0 \
-r ./siteconf20191006-3579806-yy73w4.rb extconf.rb \
--with-openssl-lib\=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0\ --with-openssl-include\=/usr/include/openssl-1.0
```

That's a known [issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6940), that was [fixed](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/7023) in `bundler-2.1.0.pre.1` and will supposedly lend into `bundler-2.1.0`.